# Importing data into Oracle via Web Enterprise Manager with unique constraints

Tags: database, oracle, import, oracle10g

I am not at all familiar with Oracle so bear with me!

I am using version Oracle 10G with the web front end called Enterprise Manager.  I have been given some CSV files to import however when I use the Load Data from User Files option I think I can set everything up but when the job runs it complains that there are unique constraints, I guess because there is duplicate data trying to be inserted.

How can I get the insert to create a new primary key similar to a MSSQL auto inc number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not have an analog to the MSSQL auto incrementing field. The feature has to be simulated via triggers and Oracle sequences. Some options here are to:

1. create a trigger to populate the columns you want auto incremented from a sequence
2. delete the offending duplicate keys in the table
3. change the values in your CSV file.

You might look at [this related SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317001/autoincrement-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

There is no autoinc type in Oracle. You have to use a `sequence`.
By using a `before insert` trigger, you could get something similar to what you get by using an autoinc in SQL Server.

You can see **[here](http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html)** how to do it.