# Oracle auto increment

Tags: oracle, auto-increment, procedure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autoincrement in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317001/autoincrement-in-oracle)

I have a table in oracle and I want to make userid auto increment.. 
Once I make it auto increment by using sequence and try to insert into table using procedure where do i put my sample.seq_userid
How do i insert userid? do i have to declare it in my procedure?

```
 PROCEDURE insertExample
  (
    name_in IN sample.name%TYPE,
    age_in IN sample.age%TYPE
  )
  IS

  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO sample
    (name, age)
    VALUES
    (name_in, age_in);

  END insertExample;
```

here is my update one

```
PROCEDURE updateExample
  (
    userid_in IN sample.userid%TYPE,
    name_in IN sample.name%TYPE,
    age_in IN sample.age%TYPE
  )
  IS

  BEGIN

    UPDATE sample
       SET name = name_in,
           age = age_in
    WHERE userid = userid_in;


  END updateExample;
```

Answer (score 4):

you need a sequence:

```
create sequence seq_user_id start with 1 increment by 1;
```

and a trigger on a table

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_id_trg 
   BEFORE insert 
   ON sample 
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      SELECT seq_user_id.NEXTVAL INTO :new.user_id FROM dual;

END;
/
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't _need_ a trigger if you specify `seq_user_id.NEXTVAL` in the INSERT statement, such as `INSERT INTO sample (user_id, name, age) VALUES (seq_user_id.NEXTVAL, name_in, age_in)` in the example given.  There can be performance advantages to specifying the sequence in the INSERT statement instead of relying on the trigger, but these might be more significant with `INSERT INTO...SELECT` than with `INSERT INTO...VALUES`.